# PIC24EP: What exactly are IOL, IOH currents

Tags: pic

I'm going through the 'Electrical Characteristics' section of datasheet of PIC24EP128GP206 to find out minimum and maximum voltages and currents specific to GPIO pins.

While doing so, I came across the terms IOL, IOH in the following section:

[image]

What do the IOL, IOH currents exactly represent? 
Are these the sourcing / sinking currents associated with the output pins?
Why is the IOH limit is mentioned negative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is the IOH limit is mentioned negative?

It's just a convention thing. Normally currents into the device (supply currents etc.) are attributed positive values therefore, currents from chip pins are given a negative sign.

> What do the IOL, IOH currents exactly represent? Are these the
>   sourcing / sinking currents

- IOL is the current **into** the pin (sinking) when the pin has a logic level of zero.
- IOH is the current **from** the pin (sourcing) when the pin has a logic level of one.

All the data in the table in the question refer to the pins being outputs (3rd column of table).

Answer (score 1):

For a VOH test, the GPIO must act as a constant-current load, and for a VOL test, the GPIO must act as a constant-current source. Before any pin is connected, the GPIO  should be set to source or sink the desired current, then, once the pin under test has been connected a voltage measurement should be performed.

thats how they are calculated from the output driver resistance:

VOH = VCC – IOH * ROH

VOL = IOL * ROL